# Can ここ be used to present a list? Or is it only used for locations?

Tags: words

If you wanted to present a word or a list of words, can you introduce it/them with ここ？

For example, "Here is what happened yesterday..."

Or is it used just in the literal sense of a location?

Comment: I think これ is the word you want. For example, 昨日の出来事はこれだ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, no, you cannot use ここ to translate English phrases like "Here you go" and "Here are the details ...". You may use これ (lit. "this"), こちら (politer version of これ), 以下 (lit. "the following"), etc., depending on what you want to say.

But ここ can refer to some point within a discussion. ここで safely means "At this point, (let's review ...)" or "Here, (X means ...)".

Answer (score 1):

Can ここ be used to present a list?
I don't think so.
According to the dictionary, ここ can be used to express location or time:
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/26097/meaning/m1u/%E6%AD%A4%E5%87%A6/

"Here is what happened" is an English idiom that should not be translated literally.

In the case of "Here is what happened yesterday..." I would say something like:
昨日の出来事は次の通りだ...